# NPM - How do you force legacy peer deps on a per project basis?

Tags: npm

How do you force legacy peer deps on a per project basis?

Would like to add this configuration to a legacy project that i need to get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a file .npmrc to the root of the project where the package.json is stored.

Once you create this file; you can set the settings and add it to version control:

**./.npmrc**

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

or if you prefer a one-liner

```
$ echo 'legacy-peer-deps=true' > .npmrc
```

If you would like to store it on a global basis you would just store it wherever you set your npm prefix configuration: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders